# How can I use PDA with odoo

Tags: odoo

I purchased a mobile terminal windows and I want to use it with Odoo and more exactly with inventory management. There is an application window Odoo Mobile 6.5 or other solution

Answer (score 0):

According to Odoo's [blog](https://www.odoo.com/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-releases-a-new-crm-mobile-app-277), Odoo CRM mobile app released in Google Playstore which is android compatible. I have no idea if it will be released for Windows Mobile 6.5 or not.